# Image Moves Down on Resize CSS

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing, codepen

All I am trying to do is put the profile picture image on the side of the text and get it to stay there. However, the image moves down and off the block when the window is at full size, as shown in the link. I've tried so many different solutions and none seem to work, would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Here is the link: https://codepen.io/Tantlu/full/JjyVrZZ

```css
body, html, main {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: justify;
}

.img1 {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: right;
}

/* Blocks */

.block {
  padding: 70px 150px;
}

.block-light {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black; 
}

.block-dark {
  background-color: #080c14;
  color: white;  
}

/* Parrallax */

.px1, .px2, .px3 {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.px1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/e5bfc63c34477d3e1b648a4f09aa9afb/tumblr_p5lsy5Ac1H1uhx88zo1_500.gifv');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.px2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(https://www.wallpaperflare.com/static/155/335/658/digital-art-artwork-landscape-sword-wallpaper.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

.px3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(https://mocah.org/uploads/posts/583541-sword-art-online.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

@media(max-width: 568px) {
  .px1, .px2, .px3{background-attachment: scroll;}
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

<div class="px1">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>手塚 治虫</h2>
    <h1 id="title">Osamu Tezuka</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block block-light">
  <h3>The father of anime</h3>
  <img class="img1" src="https://www.otaquest.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/osamu-tezuka-01.jpg"/>
  <p>Known as the Godfather of Manga and Anime, Osamu Tezuka (手塚 治虫) was born 3rd November, 1928 and died February 9th, 1989. Tezuka was a Japanese manga artist, animator and cartoonist. In 1968 he founded Tezuka Productions Co (手塚プロダクション) and Mushi Productions.</p>
</div>

<div class="px2">
  <span class="border">
    Sword Art Online
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `display: flex;` to your `block-light` class and aligned everything to the center. Also, for good measures, I added a class called `left` to avoid off word spacing, I added `text-align: center;` you can do whatever. I would suggest using `media queries` to adjust the sizing of all the applicable elements for a responsive design. Also, added `flex-direction: column;` in `media queries`

```css
body, html, main {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: 'Lexend', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: left;
}

.left {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

/* media queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .left {
    text-align: : center;
  }
  .block-light {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  /* img resizing -> min-width: 178px */
  .img1 {
    min-width: 178px !important;
    min-height: auto;
  }
}



.img1 {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: right;
}

/* Blocks */

.block {
  padding: 70px 150px;
}

.block-light {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.block-dark {
  background-color: #080c14;
  color: white;  
}

/* Parrallax */

.px1, .px2, .px3 {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.px1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url('https://64.media.tumblr.com/e5bfc63c34477d3e1b648a4f09aa9afb/tumblr_p5lsy5Ac1H1uhx88zo1_500.gifv');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.px2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(https://www.wallpaperflare.com/static/155/335/658/digital-art-artwork-landscape-sword-wallpaper.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

.px3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(0,0,0,.3)), url(https://mocah.org/uploads/posts/583541-sword-art-online.jpg);
  min-height: 400px;
}

@media(max-width: 568px) {
  .px1, .px2, .px3{background-attachment: scroll;}
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

<div class="px1">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>手塚 治虫</h2>
    <h1 id="title">Osamu Tezuka</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="block block-light">
  <h3>The father of anime</h3>
  <img class="img1" src="https://www.otaquest.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/osamu-tezuka-01.jpg"/>
  <p class="left">Known as the Godfather of Manga and Anime, Osamu Tezuka (手塚 治虫) was born 3rd November, 1928 and died February 9th, 1989. Tezuka was a Japanese manga artist, animator and cartoonist. In 1968 he founded Tezuka Productions Co (手塚プロダクション) and Mushi Productions.</p>
</div>

<div class="px2">
  <span class="border">
    Sword Art Online
  </span>
</div>
```

Click **full-page**

**EDIT:** - added a sample `media query` that changes `font-size` below 850px.

Comment: Thanks! It looks great and works well on that side. The only question now is, is there a way for the image to reach a certain size and stay at that size when resizing downwards. At the moment it completely disappears off the screen once the screen size gets too small.

Comment: I was looking at the media queries you put originally and managed to work it all out, so thank you again. Here is the final result: https://codepen.io/Tantlu/full/dyzrxgZ. And I 100% would upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet. As soon as I get enough I will!

Answer (score 0):

The image has `float:right` set which is fine, and probably what you want, when there is enough text to 'float' round the image. So it looks OK on narrower viewports.

On a wide screen it's still floated to the right but there isn't enough text to wrap around it.

Also as a float it doesn't set the height of its container.

One way to get the system to 'clear' both the text and the image before it draws the next element is to use `clear: both`

In your case put a `clear: both` in the CSS for .px2